# "Page not found" in prestashop module controller

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm developing my module and in localhost I have created tab in back office and when I click on this tab controller works fine , But when I upload this module on my real host module can create tab with no problem but when I click on this tab prestashop will show "Page not found !"

this is my code

```
        $name="My test name";
    $tab = new Tab();
    $tab->id_parent=(int)Tab::getIdFromClassName('AdminParentModulesSf');
    $tab->name=array();
    foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang){
        $tab->name[$lang['id_lang']]=$name;
    }
    $tab->class_name='AdminMyTest';
    $tab->module=$this->name;
    $tab->active=1;
    $tab->add();
```

and I have created admin/controllers/AdminMyTest.php

```
class AdminMyTestController extends ModuleAdminController
{
}
```

So , have you any idea whats wrong ? Prestashop version is 1.7.4

thanks

Comment: maybe clear the cache and uninstall / install the module ?

Comment: I have reseted my module but nothing changed !!! what do you mean by clear cash ? @VincentG

Comment: this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kOEOFjswpo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem !
I think this is Prestashop bug , when we use module class name with lower and upper case for example "MyModule" , when we create a tab , in table ps_tab module field will change to lowercase ! and when we click on tab , prestashop says page not found !

to fix this problem you should edit module field in ps_tab and change it to real name in according to lower case and upper case for example change it to "MyModule" because now this is "mymodule" or you can change your module name and name it just with lowercase !

I hope this help you